# Reverse / transpose a one-to-many map in Scala

Tags: scala, collections, dictionary

What is the best way to turn a `Map[A, Set[B]]` into a `Map[B, Set[A]]`?

For example, how do I turn a

```
Map(1 -> Set("a", "b"),
    2 -> Set("b", "c"),
    3 -> Set("c", "d"))
```

into a

```
Map("a" -> Set(1),
    "b" -> Set(1, 2),
    "c" -> Set(2, 3),
    "d" -> Set(3))
```

(I'm using immutable collections only here. And my real problem has nothing to do with strings or integers. :)

Comment: Best in what way? :) I found the preferred solutions to be much slower than mine.

Comment: Ah, right. Until I have a complete system, I always prefer conciseness and clarity over performance. (And I'm writing a full compiler, so I doubt this will be the bottle neck :)

Comment: Perfectly sound approach, but I find that sometimes conciseness and clarity don't go hand in hand... :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

with help from aioobe and Moritz:

```
def reverse[A, B](m: Map[A, Set[B]]) =
  m.values.toSet.flatten.map(v => (v, m.keys.filter(m(_)(v)))).toMap
```

It's a bit more readable if you explicitly call contains:

```
def reverse[A, B](m: Map[A, Set[B]]) =
  m.values.toSet.flatten.map(v => (v, m.keys.filter(m(_).contains(v)))).toMap
```

Comment: heh. aioobe's solution is nearly identical

Comment: Nice. I think we got a winner :D  May I suggest changing `k => ...` into just `m(_).contains(v)` :-)

Comment: Also, is `.distinct` really needed? Isn't that step taken care of in `.toMap`? After removing `.distinct` I think one could get rid of `.toSeq` as well, or am I missing something?

Comment: @aiiobe: I edited this to incorporate your m(_) change. As for the toSeq.distinct part, you're right, it isn't strictly necessary. But I figured it was better to discard the duplicates early in the computation.

Comment: @aioobe then you could go even further and write it as `m.values.toSet.flatten.map(v => (v, m.keys.filter(m(_)(v)))).toMap` - I think that is as short as it can get (as `Set[A] <: (A => Boolean)`).

Comment: @Moritz, aah, hah. Cool :-) That's what I'm using now :-) Quite hard to read now though ;-))

Answer (score 3):

Best I've come up with so far is

```
val intToStrs = Map(1 -> Set("a", "b"),
                    2 -> Set("b", "c"),
                    3 -> Set("c", "d"))

def mappingFor(key: String) =
    intToStrs.keys.filter(intToStrs(_) contains key).toSet

val newKeys = intToStrs.values.flatten
val inverseMap = newKeys.map(newKey => (newKey -> mappingFor(newKey))).toMap
```

Answer (score 3):

Or another one using folds:

```
  def reverse2[A,B](m:Map[A,Set[B]])=
      m.foldLeft(Map[B,Set[A]]()){case (r,(k,s)) =>
         s.foldLeft(r){case (r,e)=>
            r + (e -> (r.getOrElse(e, Set()) + k))
         }
      }
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a one statement solution

```
 orginalMap
 .map{case (k, v)=>value.map{v2=>(v2,k)}}
 .flatten
 .groupBy{_._1}
 .transform {(k, v)=>v.unzip._2.toSet}
```

This bit rather neatly (*) produces the tuples needed to construct the reverse map

```
Map(1 -> Set("a", "b"),
    2 -> Set("b", "c"),
    3 -> Set("c", "d"))
.map{case (k, v)=>v.map{v2=>(v2,k)}}.flatten
```

produces

```
 List((a,1), (b,1), (b,2), (c,2), (c,3), (d,3))
```

Converting it directly to a map overwrites the values corresponding to duplicate keys though

Adding `.groupBy{_._1}` gets this

```
 Map(c -> List((c,2), (c,3)),
     a -> List((a,1)),
     d -> List((d,3)), 
     b -> List((b,1), (b,2)))
```

which is closer. To turn those lists into Sets of the second half of the pairs.

```
  .transform {(k, v)=>v.unzip._2.toSet}
```

gives

```
  Map(c -> Set(2, 3), a -> Set(1), d -> Set(3), b -> Set(1, 2))
```

QED :)

(*) YMMV

Comment: Nice "stepwise" solution! +1  :-)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I can think of is:

```
// unfold values to tuples (v,k)
// for all values v in the Set referenced by key k
def vk = for {
  (k,vs) <- m.iterator
  v <- vs.iterator
} yield (v -> k)

// fold iterator back into a map
(Map[String,Set[Int]]() /: vk) {
// alternative syntax: vk.foldLeft(Map[String,Set[Int]]()) {
  case (m,(k,v)) if m contains k =>
    // Map already contains a Set, so just add the value
    m updated (k, m(k) + v)
  case (m,(k,v)) =>
    // key not in the map - wrap value in a Set and return updated map
    m updated (k, Set(v))
}
```

Comment: That looks correct, but I always find the /: syntax for folds really hard to read. Any chance you could annotate your answer with an explanation?

Comment: Added some comments. I personally prefer the `/:` to `foldLeft` and `:\ ` to `foldRight`  as it implies the order of arguments in the function / pattern match.

Answer (score 1):

A simple, but maybe not super-elegant solution:

```
  def reverse[A,B](m:Map[A,Set[B]])={
      var r = Map[B,Set[A]]()
      m.keySet foreach { k=>
          m(k) foreach { e =>
            r = r + (e -> (r.getOrElse(e, Set()) + k))
          }
      }
      r
  }
```