# Concise but readable way to calculate a map?

Tags: scala

Given,

```
case class User(name: String, roles: List[String])
val users: List[User] = ...
```

I'd like to calculate a map --

```
val roleToUsers: Map[String, List[User]] = ???
```

I could do the concise:

```
(for (user <- users; role <- user.roles) yield (role, user)).groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2))
```

But the underscores make it a bit too cryptic for my liking. Is there a neater way to do this that doesn't make it much more verbose?

**Edit:** `List[Role]` -> `List[User]`

Comment: Did you mean `Map[String, List[User]]`? That's what your example results in.

Comment: Try looking at this question for alternatives: [Reverse transpose a one to many map in scala][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498833/reverse-transpose-a-one-to-many-map-in-scala

Comment: You don't have to use anonymous functions and underscores if you don't want to.

Comment: I just tried making a version with everything fully named, as suggested by Emil, and... it was even harder to read. :(  (And usually I'm one for verboseness.)   Maybe break the statement into multiple lines, and add a couple short inline comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this:

```
val lst = for {
  user <- users
  role <- user.roles
} yield (role, users collect {
  case user if user.roles contains role => user.name
})
val map = lst.toMap
```

Or, without for-comprehensions and with a minor optimization

```
users.flatMap(_.roles).distinct.map(role => 
  (role, users collect { 
    case user if user.roles contains role => user.name })).toMap
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use pattern matching with `case` to make the naming of parameters more explicit:

```
(for { user <- users; role <- user.roles } yield (role, user)) groupBy
     { case (role, _) => role } mapValues
        { roleUser => roleUser map { case (_, user) => user} }
```

It's not much longer and a bit clearer, especially if split over a few lines. In the above the `_` are only used to mean "don't care", but you could also name everything to avoid `_` altogether:

```
(for { user <- users; role <- user.roles } yield (role, user)) groupBy
     { case (role, user) => role } mapValues
        { roleUser => roleUser map { case (role, user) => user} }
```